# Android supportability and incompatibility is so unclear

Tags: android, android-version

what is the version of android from which further on there is no concept of incompatibility(no need of support libs). I am a newbie and this supporting and non supporting thing is making it so boring. I just want to know of a stable version from which I should take start and do not use support libraries (like appcompat, sherlock, etc). Also tell me if I am doing a wrong thing doing this I mean anything that will help me. Thanks
Any relevant help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an app developer, you'd like your app to run on as many devices as possible. Generally, developers give support from API level 8 (Android 2.2) and upwards.

Most of the compatibility libraries are for pre-API 11 (HoneyComb).

So basically, it depends upon what you want to aim for.

---

### Edit

You might be interested in checking out [Choosing the right API Level for my android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961180/choosing-the-right-api-level-for-my-android-application).